# Changing the color of a box in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the colors of the boxes that I have in the HTML code with the css code that you can see below but for some reason the color does not change.

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>The Flight</li>
        <li>The City</li>
        <li>The Island</li>
        <li>The Food</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <h1>The City</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>
```

The css is as it follows

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu{
    width:25%;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:75%;
}

.main{
     width:75%;
     height:75%;
     float: left;
     border:1px solid red;
 }
```

How can I change the color of the boxes(grids)?
I am also adding the online code in case someone prefers to see :
https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/b2htLvcj/

Comment: Please provide more specific details. do u want to change the text color, border color or background color of the boxes ?

Comment: wich colors ? text, borders or background ?

Comment: Was referring to the background-color. for some reason I had to refresh my browser that's it was not applying the color. Normally its not necessary to refresh with Brackets.
But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in css background:colorcode;

```
Like This:
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.menu{
    width:25%;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
     height:75%;
     background:lightblue;
}

.main{
    width:75%;
    height:75%;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:skyblue;
}

<div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>The Flight</li>
                <li>The City</li>
                <li>The Island</li>
                <li>The Food</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <h1>The City</h1>
            <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
            <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
        </div>
```

Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/b2htLvcj/1/